# What's the difference between deleteAllInBatch() and deleteAll()?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to hibernate and spring boot. Recently, I was assigned a task to create a relational crud app. The problem is that the tutorial I am following is using JPARepository and the previous work in the code I am working on is using CRUDRepository.

My question is, can I use the function of crudRepository deleteAll() in replacement of JPARepository's method deleteAllInBatch()? Also, how different are the two interfaces?

I did not find any helpful documentation online hence the query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is yes you could use deleteAll instead of deleteAllInBatch. But you need to know that implementation of these functions are very different. 
  deleteAllInBatch do its job by using one delete query.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAllInBatch() {
    em.createQuery(getDeleteAllQueryString()).executeUpdate();
}
private String getDeleteAllQueryString() {
    return getQueryString(DELETE_ALL_QUERY_STRING, entityInformation.getEntityName());
}
public static final String DELETE_ALL_QUERY_STRING = "delete from %s x";
```

On the other hand deleteAll() leads to  findAll and after that we will iterate over all entities and invoke delete for each of them.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteAll() {

    for (T element : findAll()) {
        delete(element);
    }
}
```

As we can see deleteAll leads to N+1 requests where N is total size of target table.

Comment: so deleteAllinBatch is better? any benchmarks for this? thanks

Comment: I would like to add that while deleteAllInBatch() is faster, it should be used with caution. In our productive system, the number of objects to delete is very large. This is why I used delete in batch in the first place. However, when Hibernate translates the query to a single native query, the query string can be so long that it leads to a java.lang.StackOverflowError. Happened to me with Spring Boot 2.4.13 and Hibernate 5.4.32.